# Customize Magento REST API without OAuth

Tags: php, api, magento, rest, oauth

Is it possible to extend Magento's REST API into a custom module to work without authentication?

I've tried building a custom API based off of some internet examples, but seems to require oAuth in order to work.

Comment: what if you create a basic magento module with its own controller and you create your on rest api?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Guest endpoint. This is not very well documented; however I used Mage_Catalog as a resource when I had to do this myself. In the privileges node of api2.xml you can define permissions for create, retrieve, update or delete for a guest which will then bypass the oAuth authentication for those methods. Obviously this should be done with caution.